# Monitor the power consumption in real-time (in Ampere or Watt)

Tags: power, power-supply, voltage

I'd like to monitor in real-time the power consumption of a RPi.
(0.5A, 1A, 2A, etc.)

I know this can be done with a multimeter in ammeter mode in series, but I thought maybe there is an easier method, directly from command-line ?
After all, a RPi has many electronic features, so maybe it already has various sensors, including one for the electric current in Amperes?

Comment: You've googled this, right? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67756/measure-cpu-power-consumption-of-rpi3-with-software

Comment: @MichaelGraf Yes, but this is very specific to CPU consumption. Here I'd like the consumption of the whole RPi + the current it delivers via USB, etc.

Comment: There's also the first line of the 2nd paragraph: "I am aware of the fact that there is no tool for measuring the energy of the whole device "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good question that I've wondered myself. I don't think there is a ready-made software solution that currently exists, unfortunately. A cool idea for a project would be to build a current measuring device into the USB cable so that you can actively view the reading via a LCD or OLED display. It would just be to extract the functionality of the multimeter amp reading and integrate it directly into the USB cable via a break in the wire at that point.

Comment: *"A cool idea for a project would be to build a current measuring device into the USB cable"* -> You don't need to build one, they are called **USB ammeters**, easily found online for ~$10-20 USD.

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks, I see you're right.

Comment: @PHimmel there are panel mount/project-ready current/voltage meters in Amazon which can easily be fitted with a USB cable or directly into any project. I'm putting one in a diy laptop to monitor battery power.